# Single MySQL query for parent child table value sorting

Tags: mysql

I am facing problem to show a particular parent child value and under that child all child value as a relation ship. actually I created single table "tree" and three column id,main(as parent) and sub(as child). I created a tree relation ship but I don't understand how to fetch a particular parent child and his child and his child value for tree.

[image]

I want to show a4 parents under him the his child relation ship mean ( parent a4 child b3,b4,b5, b3 have c1 and c2, b4 have c3 and c4 and c3 have d1 and d2 this way the table value shorted out). is there any way to short the table using any mysql query??? 
if you kindly help on this. I will be glad. thank you Souvik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below:

```
select * from TreeTable a where a.main = 'a4' Union select * from TreeTable  b where b.main in (select sub from TreeTable c where c.main = 'a4')
```

1) Include "C3" use below script

```
select * from TreeTable a where a.main = 'a4' and a.main = 'c3'  Union select * from TreeTable  b where b.main in (select sub from TreeTable c where c.main = 'a4' and c.main = 'c3' )
```

2) For all childs :

```
 select * from TreeTable
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but I have some questions 1) c3 child is not included in the query. 2) is there any way to flexible this command so that the child number and sub child number doesn't matter... thank you again.

Comment: 1) I have updated question 2) I have updated question

Comment: Please let me know if you still need my help.. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. your 1) answer I try it but it is not not working. but I want to know is there any query available that do it more easily? but if I have more sub child node add under the child node and under that more child node. so that thing how I can solve it this process?? actually I want to know how to write this simply query no matter how many child steps are added with parent... Please reply soon. Thank you advance. I am looking for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well, you want to make a recursive join.

Make a join using the columns main and sub, maybe 3 joins.

I dont have a DB now for test, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this on real database and it worked - the procedure should get you all the branches, no matter how big the tree is - I hope :)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `display_tree`()
BEGIN

SET @_query_text = "";

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS result_tree;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS check_tbl;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS iter_tree;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result_tree 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tree.main as name_level0,
    tree.sub as name_level1 
FROM tree
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tree as level1_tree
        ON tree.sub = level1_tree.main
WHERE 
    tree.main NOT IN (SELECT check_tree.sub FROM  tree as check_tree);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE check_tbl 
SELECT 
    result_tree.*
FROM 
    result_tree
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tree
        ON tree.main = result_tree.name_level1
WHERE NOT(ISNULL(tree.main));


SET @current_level = 1;

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM check_tbl) DO

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS iter_tree;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE iter_tree 
    SELECT * FROM result_tree;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE result_tree;

    SET @last_level = @current_level;
    SET @current_level = @current_level + 1;

    SET @_query_text = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result_tree 
                                SELECT 
                                    iter_tree.*, 
                                    tree.sub AS name_level', @current_level, '
                                FROM 
                                    iter_tree
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN tree
                                        ON tree.main = iter_tree.name_level', @last_level);

-- SELECT @_query_text;
    PREPARE _query FROM @_query_text;

    EXECUTE _query;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _query;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE check_tbl;

    SET @_check_query_text = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE check_tbl 
                                SELECT 
                                    result_tree.*, 
                                    tree.sub AS name_level', (@current_level + 1), '
                                FROM 
                                    result_tree
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN tree
                                        ON tree.main = result_tree.name_level', @current_level, ' 
                                WHERE NOT(ISNULL(tree.main))');

    PREPARE _check_query FROM @_check_query_text;

    EXECUTE _check_query;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _check_query;
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM result_tree;

END
```

You can run it using:

```
CALL display_tree();
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply on my post.I am new in mysql so if you kindly explain it more then it will be more helpful for me.. actually I want this in my program and  I want to select any value as parent and its child and sub child value no matter what the sub child step. can you use short query for this..... but thank you.